# Sidescrolling shooter where you rescue Vietnam POWs

Tags: game-identification

I'm trying to identify a game I played this weekend. The main game appeared to be a sidescrolling shooter, where you have to shoot open cages to rescue Vietnam POWs. The environment was destructible, and there was a mission select screen where you move around a little helicopter on a spherical map. The graphics are in a pixel-style, but the game appears to be very modern. It was optionally co-op, and I played it in a polycade arcade cabinet but I suspect it is not an "arcade" game. There was an online mode as well. Anyone have any clue what I played?

[image: image from beginning of a mission]

Comment: Where did you play this that you wouldn't have been able to find out what the name of game is?

Comment: @chicks it was at a sort of art collective and the games weren't labeled. Also I'm wondering why mods deleted the comments from users reminiscing about that Atari game that shared many similarities? Seemed useful

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Looks like [Broforce](https://store.steampowered.com/app/274190/Broforce/) or [The Expendabros](https://store.steampowered.com/app/312990/The_Expendabros/). The screenshot and description match perfectly.

Comment: Looks like those games were a sort of homage to (and/or ripoff of) Metal Slug?

Comment: It's Broforce. The character(s) playing in this screenshot are [The Boondock Bros](https://broforce.fandom.com/wiki/The_Boondock_Bros) who are not in Expendabros.

Answer (score 25):

That's level two of [Broforce](https://store.steampowered.com/app/274190/Broforce/).

Here is a random Youtuber playing that level: